# Could you help me explain the meaning of "顺其自然"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I don't know what does this phrase mean in English. Please explain it with some example sentences.

Comment: Let nature take its course.

Comment: this is in dictionaries，can be called a 成语，in fact comment ＃１ above agrees with １st translation in iciba， cf。汉语熟语小词典：顺应事物自然的状态或发展方向（顺：依着）。例：我们应该正确对待简体字和繁体字并存的现象，在不同的环境下合理使用它们，顺其自然就好。

Comment: If you can't understand “顺其自然”，then I suggest you 顺其自然，some day you will know it.

Comment: The song `let it go` haunted me when I see this question.

Comment: It can also translate to "Go with the flow"

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am a Chinese, so I think I can have a try.

"顺", means let it be, or just like the song from the movie *Froze*, *let it go.*

"其", means itself.

"自然", means what it means to be.

So, put it together, it means, just let it be what it should be, do not intervene. It usually used to comfort someone who just failed something.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say let it go express the same idea here. Let it go kind of means fully express yourself the way you are, while 顺其自然 describes a future state, to let things happen naturally, accept whatever coming along the way.

So my suggestion: Let it be. As in Beetle's *Let it be*

Answer (score 0):

I am an [online Chinese tutor](http://www.ichineselearning.com/) at iChineseLearning. Hope my answer will help you.As for your question:
顺其自然 is a Chinese idiom which literally means "(let things) follow the natural way."
顺 has the meaning of "to follow, to obey"
其 is traditional Chinese, has the same meaning as the modern Chinese phrase "他的，她的 or 它的".
自然 is nature.

Maybe this example can best tell its meaning:
我们已经努力了，能不能通过考试，只能顺其自然了。
translation: We have tried our best. Whether we can pass the exam，just let nature take its course.

Answer (score 0):

顺其自然

Let things evolve following its natural ways.

It's similar to "let it be" or "see how it goes" in English.